# How to compile latest stable Mono

Tags: mono, debian

I tried

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-4.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf libgdiplus-4.2.tar.gz
cd libgdiplus-4.2
mkdir /opt/m511
./configure --prefix=/opt/m511
make
make install
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-5.11.0.89.tar.bz2
tar jxf mono-5.11.0.89.tar.bz2
cd /usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89
./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/m511
make
```

but got error

```
...
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89/mono/utils'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89/mono/utils'
  CC     os-event-unix.lo
os-event-unix.c: In function ‘mono_os_event_wait_multiple’:
os-event-unix.c:121: warning: ‘data’ may be used uninitialized in this function
os-event-unix.c:123: warning: ‘start’ may be used uninitialized in this function
  CC     mono-md5.lo
  CC     mono-sha1.lo
  CC     mono-logger.lo
  CC     mono-codeman.lo
In file included from ../../mono/metadata/metadata-internals.h:12,
                 from ../../mono/metadata/class-internals.h:12,
                 from ../../mono/metadata/profiler-private.h:10,
                 from mono-codeman.c:22:
../../mono/metadata/domain-internals.h:10:42: error: mono/metadata/object-forward.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../mono/metadata/metadata-internals.h:12,
                 from ../../mono/metadata/class-internals.h:12,
                 from ../../mono/metadata/profiler-private.h:10,
                 from mono-codeman.c:22:
../../mono/metadata/domain-internals.h:615: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MonoReflectionTypeBuilder’
make[4]: *** [mono-codeman.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89/mono/utils'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89/mono/utils'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89/mono'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.11.0.89'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to compile it  ? Mono 4.4.2 compiled OK with those commands.

Comment: Cannot you simply refer to their CI server to find a suitable build? https://jenkins.mono-project.com/job/test-mono-mainline-linux/label=debian-8-arm64/ Also their stable releases are https://github.com/mono/mono/releases so you are obviously trying something unstable by using 5.11.

Comment: I tried previous file, .64 version. It worked.